# How to avoid page reload on standardController standard action (Save)?

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, standardcontroller, action, detail-page

i am using stadardcontroller Opportunity on my visualforce page but my concern is i don't want to reload that Opportunity detail page when i click on Save Button...

Code :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" reRender="Pb1" />
```

What should i need add in this line ?

Help me out....

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try [action="{!quickSave}"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm) Standard Controller action

Comment: Cool....it's Working, Now it's not reload the whole detail page.. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Olejsiy can we have same thing for Edit action ??

Comment: Edit on standard page layout? I afraid you have no control on this.

Comment: ohhh. ACtually the thing is i have two pageBlocksection and i put QuickSave action on first PageBlocksection and it's working fine and rerender it on the next pageBlocksection but Now, i want one button on Second pageBlocksection with Name Edit and that button must rerender the first pageBlocksection with Edit Mode...is it Possible ?

Comment: You better to create another question, and provide some code

Comment: i have created one another question for this and added some code too. please check this link : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116496/how-to-avoid-page-reload-on-standard-edit-action

Answer (score 1):

Put `rerender="nothing"`, where "nothing" is an invalid element Id if you don't want to rerender anything on the page. Also, make sure you override the `Save` method and change the return type to be `void` and not `PageReference`.

Comment: but i already used reRender in my code line