# How to avoid page reload on standard Edit action?

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller, action, pageblock, edit

I have two pageBlocksection and i put QuickSave action on first PageBlocksection and it's working fine and it's rerender the next pageBlocksection but Now, i want one button on Second pageBlocksection with Name Edit and that button must rerender the first pageBlocksection with Edit Mode...is it Possible ?

i am using Edit action (Stadard action of stadard controller)

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!Edit}" reRender="Pb" status="splashStatus">
        </apex:commandButton>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

and yes let me share my screen which i need to change...

Screen 1 :
[image]

Screen 2 :
[image: User-added image]
I am getting this screen while clicking on that Button (Back) but i want **screen 3**

Screen 3 :
[image: User-added image]

Please have a look and help me out..

Thanks

Comment: have you overridden the standard Edit button with your custom VF page?

Comment: No. it's standard edit button. i am not using any custom edit button